# How to add column containing values 0...n to existing dataframe in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have existing dataframe with many columns. How to one add column containing values `0...n-1` (where `n` is number of rows in my dataframe. I can do it when I have no any dataframe, something like: `spark.range(...).toDF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number` function and substract 1 to get it starting from 0:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df1 = df.withColumn("new_col", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(null))) - 1)
```

You can order by specific column in your dataframe in place of null if the order is important.